# jQuery slice - last result

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice

Lets say I have 100 divs and I want to show 5 divs each time.
onclick - I'm loading 5 more.

Any idea how to check if I reached the last div?

```
<div id="results">1</div>
<div id="results">2</div>
<div id="results">3</div>
<div id="results">4</div>
<div id="results">100</div>

$(function () {
    $("results").slice(0, 5).show();
    $("#moreresults").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div:hidden").slice(0, 5).slideDown();
  });
});


<a href="#" id="moreresults">Load More</a>
```

Comment: No valid `HTML` here. `id`'s are supposed to be unique. You can't have 100 `id`'s with the same name.

Comment: yes i know , just a bad and quick duplication

Answer (score 2):

First of all the `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, so use common classes instead, e.g :

```
<div class="results">1</div>
<div class="results">2</div>
<div class="results">3</div>
<div class="results">4</div>
...
```

You could use `index`'s with the help of the jQuery selectors **[`lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)** and **[`gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)**, check the working example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function () {
    var number = 5;
    var count = $('.results').length;
    
    //Show just 5 first and hide the rest
    $(".results:gt("+(number-1)+")").hide();
    
    //Attach the click event
    $("#moreresults").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      //Increment the 'number'
      number = number+5;
      
        //Show 'number' of element
        $(".results:lt("+number+")").slideDown();
        
        //Check if all divs are loaded
        if( number >= count ){
           console.log('All the divs are loaded');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">1</div>
<div class="results">2</div>
<div class="results">3</div>
<div class="results">4</div>
<div class="results">5</div>
<div class="results">6</div>
<div class="results">7</div>
<div class="results">8</div>
<div class="results">9</div>
<div class="results">10</div>
<div class="results">11</div>
<div class="results">12</div>
<div class="results">13</div>
<div class="results">14</div>
<div class="results">15</div>
<div class="results">16</div>
<div class="results">17</div>
<div class="results">18</div>
<div class="results">19</div>
<div class="results">20</div>

<a href="#" id="moreresults">Load More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the last `div` is visible

```
   if($('div:last').is(":visible")) {
        //do things here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an working example for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3egqhvry/)

First you have to use class not id on the 'results', and use `$(".results:lt(5)")`

Answer (score 0):

Using `last()` and `is()`:

```js
var $results = $('.results');

$results.slice(5).hide();

$('#moreresults').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var $nextResults = $results.filter(':hidden').slice(0,5).slideDown()
   if( $nextResults.last().is( $results.last() ) ){     
     $(this).hide();
     console.log('Last one')
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results">Item 1</div>
<div class="results">Item 2</div>
<div class="results">Item 3</div>
<div class="results">Item 4</div>
<div class="results">Item 5</div>
<div class="results">Item 6</div>
<div class="results">Item 7</div>
<div class="results">Item 8</div>
<div class="results">Item 9</div>
<div class="results">Item 10</div>
<div class="results">Item 11</div>
<div class="results">Item 12</div>
<div class="results">Item 13</div>



<a href="#" id="moreresults">Load More</a>
```